# Continuously transfer files to the server

Tags: linux, scripting, scp, file-transfer, inotify

I have linux client and linux server. Both are Ubuntu 16.04.
On the client I generated .txt files almost every second, and I want to transfer them to the server, so my question is: what is the best solution for this purpose?

I did this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/home/path"

while true
do
    for entry in "$path"/*.txt
        do
            if [ -f "$entry" ]
            then
                scp "$entry" 4lkov@79.164.131.110:/home/4lkov/Desktop/scp && rm -f "$entry"
            else
                echo "No files";
            fi
        done
    sleep 1
done
```

So, I'm using SCP is it reliable or is there best ways (rsync or similar)?
Also I'm using sleep 1.. probably there is some watchdog? (i.e `inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to |` )

Comment: You already have the right answer - `inotifywait` on the directory will do the job.

Comment: Yes, what's about scp?

Comment: `scp` is fine, `rsync` is more appropriate when you have many files (which you won't have unless you make the `inotifywait` code more complex by accumulating filenames for a while between transfers). `rsync` does have an option to remove the source file on completion of the transfer, though, if that is needed.

Comment: Mount the remote machine using `sshfs` and just create the files on the remote machine to start with?

Comment: I would probably use something like Syncthing for this, or mount the directory as a NFS share.

Answer (score 0):

This script loops forever over every file in `$path` and opens a SCP connection to transfer each file individually, pausing every second. This has a high overhead. Better use `rsync` instead to synchronize the directory from server to client.

Comment: Well, rsync do the same, isn't? (I mean opens connection) `rsync -avz *.txt root@<remote-ip>:/home/test`  *I need to remove file after it was sent.

Comment: Using a tool made for the job (`rsync` in this case) is better than reinventing the wheel.